# Should I give up grammatical correctness when naming my functions to offer regularity?

Tags: naming-conventions

I implement several global functions in our library that look something like this:

```
void init_time();
void init_random();
void init_shapes();
```

I would like to add functions to provide a check whether those have been called:

```
bool is_time_initialized();
bool is_random_initialized();
bool are_shapes_initialized();
```

However, as you can see `are_shapes_initialized` falls out of the row due to the fact that `shapes` is plural and therefore the function name must start with ***are*** and not ***is***. This could be a problem, as the library is rather large and not having a uniform way to group similiar functions under the same naming convention might be confusing / upsetting.

E.g. a user using IntelliSense quickly looking up function names to see if the libary offers a way to check if their initialization call happened:

[image: IntelliSense only displaying "is_" functions]

They won't find **`are_shapes_initialized()`** here unless scrolling through hundreds of additional function / class names.

Just going with **`is_shapes_initialized()`** could offer clarity:

[image: IntelliSense displaying now all "is_initialized" functions]

As this displays all functions, now.

But how can using wrong grammar be a good approach? Shouldn't I just assume that the user should also ask IntelliSense for "are_initialized" or just look into the documentation in the first place? Probably not, right? Should I just give up on grammatical correctness?

Comment: I'd say yes. A library can be a joy or a headache to use. Usually, when things are consistent and easy to find (i.e. you can use it without having to refer to the documentation), it is a joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, a variable is a single entity. Maybe that entity is an aggregate of other entities, such as an array or a collection, in which case it would make sense to give it a plural name e.g. a set of `Shape` objects could be called `shapes`. Even so, it is still a single object. Looking at it that way, it is grammatically acceptable to refer to it as singular. After all, `is_shapes_initialized` actually means "Is the variable 'shapes' initialized?"

It's the same reason we say "*The Bahamas is*" or "*The Netherlands is*", because we are referring to the singular country, not whatever plural entity it is comprised of. So yes, `is_shapes_initialized` can be considered grammatically correct.

Comment: It's weird because when I looked at `is_shapes_initialized` it didn't feel completely incorrect for some reason. You just explained that exact feeling and now I can feel good about naming these functions that way, thanks~

Answer (score 2):

It's more a matter of personal taste. I would recommend putting "is" before functions that return Boolean. This would look more like:

```
bool is_time_initialized();
bool is_random_initialized();
bool is_shapes_initialized();
```

This makes them easier to find and search for, even if they aren't grammatically correct.

You can find functions using "are" to show it is plural in places such as the DuckDuckGo app, with:

```
areItemsTheSame(...)
areContentsTheSame(...)
```

In the DuckDuckGo app, it also uses "is" to show functions return boolean, and boolean variables:

```
val isFullScreen: Boolean = false
isAssignableFrom(...)
```

In OpenTK, a C# Graphics Library, I also found usage of "are":

```
AreTexturesResident(...)
AreProgramsResident(...)
```

In the same OpenTK Libary, they use "is" singularly for functions that return boolean and boolean variables:

```
IsEnabledGenlock(...)
bool isControl = false;
```

Either usage could work. Using "are" plurally would make more sense grammatically, and using "if" plurally could make more sense for efficiency or simplifying Boolean functions.

Comment: in DuckDuckGo and OpenTK do they also use the `Is()` naming for singular cases?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do, assuming you are trying to avoid calling this function on each shape.

```
void init_each_shape();

bool is_each_shape_initialized();
```

Also assuming that you need these functions, it seems like it would make more sense to have the functions throw an exception if they do not succeed.

Comment: that is also a clever Workaround worth considering. For now I will go with `is_shapes_initialized` as the accepted answer pointed the validity of that out. What speaks for your approach is that it is more intuitively readable, but also adds one extra word to the length.